# How do I get the 2 year period for each semi annual date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series index `tidx` that I want to break up into 2 year chunks.  This is my clumsy way of doing it.

***define `tidx` and companion `tdf`***

```
tidx = pd.date_range('1996-12-31', periods=8, freq='2Q')
tdf = pd.DataFrame(tidx.rename('date'), tidx.rename('tidx'))
tdf
```

[image]

***define period index `pidx` and companion `p_lookup`***

```
pidx = pd.period_range(tidx[0], tidx[-1], freq='2A-NOV')
ps = lambda x: pd.Series([x, x.start_time], ['period', 'date'])
p_lookup = pidx.to_series().apply(ps)
p_lookup
```

[image]

***use `pd.merge_asof` to get the `pd.Period` object per `tidx`***
this is what I'm after

```
pd.merge_asof(tdf, p_lookup).set_index('date').period

date
1996-12-31   1997
1997-06-30   1997
1997-12-31   1997
1998-06-30   1997
1998-12-31   1999
1999-06-30   1999
1999-12-31   1999
2000-06-30   1999
Name: period, dtype: object
```

***What's an efficient / less clumsy way of doing this?***

Comment: I don't think it's clumsy, it actually gives you an explicit period lookup table that is flexible when you will want to deal with weird periods like FY ends etc. So what is inefficient from your perspective?

Comment: many steps.  I feel that with the plethora of time and period functions, that there must be a more succinct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic of creating a lookup `DF` to compare is very similar to yours. The only change is that the generation of the annual frequency can be quickly done by using the `asfreq` function on the dataframe and we only need to retrieve those indices.

Lookup can be made by offsetting these dates by an year(lagging) and allowing it to start from the next day onwards. Like before, `merge_asof` can be performed to match the dates on the nearest values.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import * 

idx = tdf.asfreq('2A-NOV').index
lk_up = pd.DataFrame({'date': idx-DateOffset(years=1)+Day(1), 'period': idx.year})
pd.merge_asof(tdf, lk_up)
```

[image]

***Note:*** The period obtained is of type `int` and not of Period object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by just using tidx, yet it implies you do the math subtraction from your starting point:

```
nb_years = 2

a = tidx.to_period('1A-NOV').to_series()

a
Out[145]: 
1997   1997
1997   1997
1998   1998
1998   1998
1999   1999
1999   1999
2000   2000
2000   2000
Freq: A-NOV, dtype: object

a.mask((a - a[0]).mod(nb_years) !=0, np.nan).ffill()
Out[146]: 
1997   1997
1997   1997
1998   1997
1998   1997
1999   1999
1999   1999
2000   1999
2000   1999
Freq: A-NOV, dtype: object
```